# Filter data using a loop to compare calculated metrics for different days of week in R

Tags: r, function, loops, traffic

I have a data set of traffic by day and by hour. I have written a function that I would like to apply to different conditions of this data set.

For instance, I want to compare average traffic for different days of the week and different hours of the day.

How do I use a loop to filter through each possibility day of week and return the metric i have a function for, for each of them?

Would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. It will explain how to add appropriate data with a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a loop is the best thing for what you're trying to do, but here's one way to do it.

```
# generate example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(hour    = sample(1:24, 100, T), 
                 dow     = sample(1:7, 100, T), 
                 traffic = round(runif(100, 1, 50)))

# prep storage matrix for results
H <- sort(unique(df$hour))
D <- sort(unique(df$dow))
res_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(H), ncol=length(D))
colnames(res_mat) <- D
rownames(res_mat) <- H

# function I want to apply to subsets of values
my_fun <- function(x) { mean(x) + 2 }

# loop
for(h in seq_along(H)) {
for(d in seq_along(D)) {
    # get vector of traffic for a particular hour and day-of-week combo
    subset_of_traffic <- df[df$hour == H[h] & df$dow == D[d], "traffic"]

    # skip if no traffic data for this hour and day-of-week combo
    if(length(subset_of_traffic)==0) next

    # run function on that subset and store result
    res_mat[h,d] <- my_fun(subset_of_traffic)
}
}
```

A faster way to get the same results with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
res_dt <- dt[ , .(results = my_fun(traffic)), by=.(hour, dow)]
```